# Getting 'Undefined' value outside Fetch API

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I am new in react native, trying to assign fetch API response value to a local variable. But outside function shows an undefined value of the variable.

Here is code

```
const {
    diesel_data
} = this.state

let currentHMR
let previous_HMR
let previous_EstEngHours
let isViolationPass_HMR

let asset_id = diesel_data[0].diselRequisitionDetails[0].asset_id
let current_hmr = diesel_data[0].diselRequisitionDetails[0].current_hmr
let requisitionId = diesel_data[0].requisitionId

this._indicator.startActivity()
fetch(url + 'Norms/DieselHmrViolation/' + asset_id + '/' + current_hmr + '/' + requisitionId, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
        this._indicator.stopActivity()
        var list = json;
        console.log(list)
        if (!isBlank(list)) {
            currentHMR = list.currentHMR
            previous_HMR = list.previous_HMR
            previous_EstEngHours = list.previous_EstEngHours
            isViolationPass_HMR = list.isViolationPass_HMR

        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

console.log('currentHMR', currentHMR)
```

Comment: javascript won't wait for the fetch to complete before running this line `console.log('currentHMR', currentHMR)`

Comment: @ksav So what should i do now

Comment: move the `console.log('currentHMR', currentHMR)` to just after `currentHMR = list.currentHMR`

Comment: @ksav but i want the value outside

Comment: Easiest way would be to set the value returned from fetch to component state. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: @ksav Okay Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do like this, wait until executing fetch *(maybe you have to move this inside a [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function)*

```
let data;

await fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/2', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => data = res)
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

console.log('data', data);
```